# Showing 5 images in a row (Responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm trying to display 5 images in a row using Bootstrap. My current code is below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-2" *ngFor="let smiley of agtContentService.smileys">
      <figure>
        <img src="{{smiley.image}}" width="150" height="150">
        <figcaption>{{smiley.name}}</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem currently is that when the images are displayed they are not centered on the screen. Also, they don't stretch/compress depending on screen size. For iOS it is not responsive at all. Can anyone help? What I'm trying to achieve are the below:

1. Display 5 images with their captions in a row where they take the whole screen size without overlapping and with some space between them.
2. If the screen size is much smaller (like a mobile phone) they should become smaller up to a specified minimum size and after that, they start to wrap (for e.g. for really small devices, show the images in a column).
3. Need to work on Android, iOS, Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: How badly do you want to rely on Bootstrap grid system? Can it be completely custom css? Would it be okay to have a far-left and far-right margin?

Comment: The rest of the site is using bootstrap, but if can get it to work with custom style is okay. far left and right margins okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below code in your style sheet and tune using the variables.

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
  }

.col {
    flex: 1 0 150px;
    margin: 1em;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 1em;
  }
```

This is a work around suggested by bootstrap for their flexbox issue with safari and ios.

you can read more about it using the below link

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Below is a working example

https://codepen.io/philipwalton/pen/RPMqjz

Answer (score 1):

Use `<img class="img-responsive"`>

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-2" *ngFor="let smiley of agtContentService.smileys">
      <figure>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{smiley.image}}" width="150" height="150">
        <figcaption>{{smiley.name}}</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give  below css properties to image tag.

```
.col-sm-2 img{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

You can find my example here.
https://jsfiddle.net/sree296/DTcHh/39349/